# MVC SPA Images all return 404

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I created a new MVC site .NET Framework 4.6.2 with Individual user accounts and  added angular

and am serving up partial razor pages and angular through the area section.

I tried to place an image into the _Layout and couldn't get it to work, then abandoned that to just put an image in a  in one of my partials.

```
 <div style="padding-top:25px">

 I'm the Test page

 <img src="~/Content/WeCare.jpg" />
 <img src='<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Images/WeCare.jpg")%>' alt="Test Pic" 
 />

 </div>

 <ui-view></ui-view>
```

I've tried every configuration of adding the image and changed the location of the images based on other posts I read and nothing works?  I just get 404's

I've even tried adding...

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

          app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
```

to my Startup.cs because someone told me this is what was missing.

I must really be missing something or not understand how this works at all because it shouldn't be this hard to add an image to a web page.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you checked how it`s generating the HTML ? Is the path wrong after the page is rendered ?

Comment: No, how do I do that @BrunoQuintella ?

Comment: You can use Chrome DevTools to inspect your HTML.

Comment: @BrunoQuintella Then yes...I already checked this, image path = "http://localhost/WeCare/Content/WeCare.jpg " this is the correct path.  I also browsed directly from IIS and get a 404???  It's crazy!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, After countless hours of searching and trying different things I tried browsing a .css file that was in the same directory as the image I was trying to show...It worked.
I looked in the web.config and noticed that both ".css" and ".jpg" had entried in the  section...

```
<add name="JavascriptHandler" path="*.js" verb="GET" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
 <add name="CssHandler" path="*.css" verb="GET" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```

I added a handler like these for images, this one for .jpg...

```
 <add name="ImageHandler" path="*.jpg" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"/>
```

...and  worked!!!

I'm still not sure why this is set up like this but it is.